Wallet Selector for Polkadot.js Apps UI
Are the maintainers of Polkadot.js Apps UI receptive to integrating with a wallet selector? Is there a reason why Polkadot.js Apps UI is not integrated with the Talisman Connect wallet selector?

I think the best way to get an answer to this is to make an issue in the pjs/apps repo so you can get an answer straight from the apps team.

The Issue template for that repo says questions should be asked here.

From the template: " [...] issues in this repository are meant for the tracking of feature requests". This looks like a feature request so its pertinent to the repo's issues. Also it would be more direct to straight up ask the team instead of asking here, they won't be angry or anything at you for just asking.
